# BackgroundWorker и два разных события DoWork

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

Как в событии `DoWork` сделать два разных обработчика? У меня есть две задачи которые нужно отображать в прогресс-бар.

Если так:

```
backgroundworker.DoWork += bgw_DoWork1
backgroundworker.DoWork += bgw_DoWork2
```

То как вызывать для каждой задачи свое событие?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте для каждой задачи свой `Backgroundworker`.

Или переходите на альтернативные варианты выполнения фоновых задач, например [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) + [IProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: А что использовали бы вы, в таком случае?

Comment: @Максим задачи (Task). Но это я, вам надо использовать то, что вам удобнее.

Comment: А с точки зрения производительности, что эффективнее?

Comment: @Максим производиьельность определяется полезной нагрузкой, а не способом запуска

Comment: Спасибо большое)